# Rotman's Homological Algebra Problem 3.42 (without using direct limits)

Tags: homological-algebra

This is Problem 3.42 from Rotman's Homological Algebra text.

### Claim

Let $ 0 \to B' \to B \to B'' \to 0$ be an exact sequence of left $R$-modules. If the sequences remains exact after tensoring with all finitely presented right $R$-modules then the sequence is pure exact.

### Question

I see that this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2311480/tensoring-short-exact-sequence-being-exact-for-all-finitely-presented-modules-im) provides a proof. Even though the poster tried to prove this without direct limits, this proof was never explicitly given.

Can someone please provide a hint for a direct proof without using direct limits, or at least fill in more details that weren't included in this other post?

Comment: Is the exact sequence correct like this? Currently, you have an isomorphism between $B'$ and $B''$.

Comment: @Tzimmo Sorry for the typo -- just fixed. Same as it appears in the other post.

Comment: Should “remains pure exact” be “remains exact”?

Comment: Yes, sorry again!

Comment: What is the motivation for finding a proof that avoids the most natural and easy approach here?

Comment: Rotman doesn't address direct limits until a later chapter, so I'm curious how to write the proof with only the tools of the first 3 chapters.

Comment: In a sense, "direct limits" is just (excellent) language to describe something that can be broken down into more concrete terms. You can unwind a (co)limit based approach and you should be able to obtain a clear proof.

Comment: Ok -- I've reviewed the proof in the other post more closely, and see that Chapter 5 addresses this. The proof is quite simple once I understand direct limits.